# Displaying json data from server in basic html table using for loop, javascript only, problem with for loop?

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, html-table

I have the following Javascript code:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/CarSales/rest/cars", true);
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
        var status = request.status;
        if (status === 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400)){
            var cars = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            var output = "";
            for(var i in cars){
                output ='<tr><td>'+cars[i].make+'</td><td>'+cars[i].model+'</td><td>'+cars[i].year+'</td> <td>'+cars[i].engine+'</td></tr>';
            }

            document.getElementById('table-body').innerHTML = output;
        }else{
            console.log("error");
        }
    }
};  
request.send();
```

and the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="js/Q4.js"></script>

<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Engine</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="table-body"></tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Currently it outputs the last object of the json data in the table correctly:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V73pC.png

How do I get the JS code to output all json objects into the table? Perhaps by changing the for loop to iterate through the json data?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to append on every loop. just add after output **+**= ""; its not appending that's the reason displaying only last loop value.

```
for(var i in cars){
    output +='<tr><td>'+cars[i].make+'</td><td>'+cars[i].model+'</td><td>'+cars[i].year+'</td> <td>'+cars[i].engine+'</td></tr>';
}
```